# Is there any sort of online kernel repository or sharing sites (possibly for laptops)

Tags: kernel, repository

It just seems there should reasonably be something like this considering so many folks run *nix on laptops and laptops have such consistent hardware sets. At a guess I'd imagine there's likely in the ~1000-2000 range of hardware combinations making up ~85% of laptops in current use (this is completely random guess off the top of my head).

That said, does anyone know of any sites where people share their precompiled kernels or .configs? I used to meddle them up myself; but that was ~10 years ago and I don't frankly want the headache of getting my hardware working myself. Would be awesome if I could just go to a website, start selecting hardware my machine has and it filters down to other peoples shared .config files, or I could just put in my laptop's model number and it finds someone elses posted .config who had the same.

On a side note, yes the common default kernels distros come with seem to work fine on my laptop, but I'm struggling to get the ATI drivers working correctly (I understand I need to remove DRI/KMS and stand on my head while doing some other things; so far I've managed to boot to a black screen in my latest kernel recompile attempt) but it seems somebody else has probably wrestled this into submission on their machine, and their should be a site they can share it in a more concrete form than tutorial.

Comment: Hardly, geeks tune their kernel config manually, as the number of new laptop models is growing, I doubt you can find the "latest" config

Comment: Several people I work with were just talking about the lack of such a resource.  Sounds like one should be made (flexes fingers and prepares to code)

Comment: @warl0ck I'm less interested in solving my problem at this point (I have sufficient troubleshooting skills to get it resolved myself) than I am in if a sharing site of any sort like this might exist. It just seems like a neat idea that should exist if it doesn't. I wager you and most geeks would share their .config and some hardware specs to such a site if it existed

Comment: If you run a Thinkpad X220, I could give you a minimized config, I eliminated all unnecessary module

Comment: @warl0ck I appreciate it but nope, it's an acer with ATI switchable graphics which is the cause of the pain. That and the fact that I was searching for a minimal install of ubuntu so it didn't come preconfigured with other drivers but failed and installed it pre-configured with X and everything else all set to work off non-ati drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't need to custom compile kernels these days; the distribution provided generic ones should just work.  They just throw all the drivers in as modules and they get loaded as needed.

Comment: I understand this, but I'm still curious about an online kernel config repository existing.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa, there isn't one because there is no need.

Comment: Maybe no *need* but that doesn't mean there's no use. Many websites have large active communities simply because they're useful but totally unnecessary, for example, this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a github repository to keep '.config' files because I use Gentoo and hope other users can contribute making easy to install it in a new laptop. Anyway is hard to have the right '.config' because some options doesn't depend on which hardware you have but could serve as a base to start customizing your own kernel.

https://github.com/alej0varas/puntoconfig/